# WP_Post is not from correct array

Tags: php, loop, array

A bit of a complicated problem here, but I figured I'd see if I could get any help.

My logic is this:

WordPress custom post query > for each of the results, factor in distance (calculated separately), based on a conditional push the result to an array ($results) > Sort results > for each of the results, display proper WP data.

I got everything working correctly up until the last part.

```
// initial wordpress query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team-members',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'specialties',
            'value' => $_GET['specialization'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $loop->get_posts();

// create array for results
$results = array();

foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    $loop->the_post();

    $result_lat = get_post_meta( $value->ID, 'latitude', true );
    $result_long = get_post_meta( $value->ID, 'longitude', true );
    $distance = round(calc_distance($input_lat, $input_lng, $result_lat, $result_long, "M"));

    // add item to results if within distance
    if ($distance < $_GET['within']) {
        $results[$key]['values'] = $value;  
        $results[$key]['distance'] = $distance; // add distance to array
    }
}

// sort results by distance
usort($results, function($a, $b) { return $a["distance"] - $b["distance"]; });

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    echo get_the_ID();
}
```

In the case of `get_the_ID()`, it's not getting the correct post ID. Instead, it's just going back to the original query.

If I do a `var_dump($results)` before the last loop, I get an array that's structured like:

```
array(3) {
[0]=> array(2) {
    ["values"]=> object(WP_Post)#659 (24) {
        ["ID"]=> int(300)
        ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1"
```

I need to set WP_Post to be at the correct array for each of these items, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: You should sanitise and escape the `$_GET` values to prevent injection attacks

Comment: I'm getting the idea this is very ineffecient and can be made more effecient with the proper adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_ID` gives you the ID of the current post, but at no point during that loop do you change what **the** current post is. It's always the last post processed in the previous loop because that's the last time you called `the_post()`. This is why you always get the same ID.

Instead, store the ID:

```
$results[$key]['ID'] = $value->ID;
```

Then echo that instead:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['ID'];
}
```

Another important issues is that you're using `$results[$key]` but you never assign it an initial value, and assume it's an array, you should initialise it using `$results[$key] = arrayy();` first

Comment: This didn't seem to work

Comment: Can you be more specific, how did it not work, what did it do instead?